# string methods in python

Tags: python, string, indexing

I need help on how to define and test three functions on strings. Following these guidelines. This is review for my exam on Wednesday and would really like to have the correct solutions because mine are all coming back with the syntax errors.

I need to come up with the code for all three examples following the requirements listed below.

Without using any string methods only `len` function and the string operations `+`, `*`, indexing slicing, and `==` for comparing strings or characters.

In the `repl` function, use the accumulator pattern to build up the new string.

### Examples

1. The `ends` function takes a string as argument; if the string has two or more characters, it returns a string consisting of the first and last character of the given string; otherwise, it returns the given string.

   ```
   >>> ends("ab")
   'ab'
   >>> ends("abc")
   'ac'
   >>> ends("a long sentence")
   'ae'
   >>> ends("")
   ''
   >>> ends("*")
   '*'
   ```
2. The `butends` function takes a string argument; if the string has two or more characters, it returns a string consisting of all but the first and last character of the string; otherwise, it returns the given string.

   ```
   >>> butends("abcde")
   'bcd'
   >>> butends("abc")
   'b'
   >>> butends("a long sentence")
   ' long sentenc'
   >>> butends("")
   ''
   >>> butends("a")
   'a'
   ```
3. The repl function takes three arguments:

   - `old` is a single character;
   - `new` is a string of 0 or more characters;
   - `s` is any string.

   I know that it returns a new string formed by replacing every occurrence of old in s with new.

   ```
   >>> repl('a', 'A', 'fast faces react snappily')
   'fAst fAces reAct snAppily'
   >>> repl('*', '+++', 'a*b = c*d')
   'a+++b = c+++d'
   >>> repl(' ', '\n', 'Practice every day.')
   'Practice\nevery\nday.'
   >>> print(repl(' ', '\n', 'Practice every day.'))
   Practice
   every
   day.
   >>> repl(",", ":", "a,b,cde,fghi")
   'a:b:cde:fghi'
   ```

what I have so far for part 3 is:

```
 def repl(old, new, s):
     newStr = ""
     for ch in s:
         if ch != old:
             newStr = newStr + ch
         else:
             newStr = newStr + new
     return newStr
```

The code listed above does not replace the correct characters I'm not sure where I went wrong.

Comment: I'm sure more people will say this, but what have you tried?

Comment: *“[…] would really like to have the correct solutions because mine are all coming back with the syntax errors.”* – Show us *your* solutions and what doesn’t work, and we’ll try to help you fix them. You learn a lot more from having your own ideas corrected, than just getting complete functions.

Comment: Strikes me that with these constraints, the third question is massively harder than the first two.

Comment: [What have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: The first two can be easily done with index slicing. For the third one, use your hint :).

Comment: I have been looking at multiple code/operators in the "Python Programming in Context" textbook and have come up with certain operations but I fail with combining all of it.

Comment: Oh, the string to replace is only one character never mind then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one possible solution for the three functions. Note that, as I mentioned above in the comments, you would learn a lot more if you would show us what you have tried and what the problems with it are.

```
def ends (s):
    if len(s) > 2:
        return s[0] + s[-1]
    else:
        return s

def butends (s):
    if len(s) > 2:
        return s[1:-1]
    else:
        return s

def repl (find, replacement, s):
    newString = ''
    for c in s:
        if c == find:
            newString += replacement
        else:
            newString += c
    return newString
```

Comment: If `str.join` is allowed: `''.join(replacement if c == find else c for c in s)`

Comment: @StevenRumbalski I consider `str.join` a *“string method”* though ;)

Comment: Yep -- that's why I qualified my statement.  However, `str.join` does feel different conceptually than the other string methods.

Comment: for the 3rd example I believe there needs to be a return statement at the bottom of it but not sure what exactly needs to be returned

Comment: Ok, I tried that but when I run the module in Python Shell I end up with just 'm' instead of "miththiththippi"

Answer (score 1):

1. If you can use `len()` and slicing, it would be best to simply grab
   the first and last characters and return that.

   ```
   def ends(input):
       if len(input) < 2:
           return input
       else:
           return input[0] + input[-1]
   ```
2. You can pretty much do the same thing here:

   ```
   def butends(input):
       if len(input) < 2:
           return input
       else:
           return input[1:-1]
   ```
3. For this one, there's a function in Python called `replace`, but I'm
   not sure you can use it.

   ```
   def repl(old, new, input):
       return input.replace(old, new)
   ```

If you can't, then simply loop through the input and replace each character whenever it matches with new.

Comment: _then simply loop through the input and replace each character whenever it matches with new._ Note that this cannot be done with strings because they are immutable. So OP will have to convert the string to list to do this. Or create a new string

Comment: ^ Smac89 is correct, you will need to create a new string, and copy characters over when they do not match, and replace them when they do.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
def ends(s):
    if len(s)<=2: return s
    return s[0]+s[-1]
```

2)

```
def butends(s):
    if len(s)<=2: return s
    return s[1:-1]
```

3)

```
def repl(s,old,new):
    return s.replace(old,new)
```

Comment: _Without using any string methods_ (for the 3rd one)

Answer (score 0):

I like programming assignments:

```
def ends (s): return s [0] + s [-1] if len (s) > 1 else s
def butends (s): return s [1:-1] if len (s) > 1 else s
def repl (a, b, c, acc = ''): return acc if not c else repl (a, b, c [1:], acc + (b if c [0] == a else c [0] ) )
```

Not sure what an "accumulator pattern" is, so for the replacement I used a recursive function with an accumulator as known from functional programming.

Comment: `ends` and `butends` produce wrong solutions for `'a'`. Also: recursive solution for `repl`? That might be a bit over the top ^^ (I like it anyway :P)

Comment: Not sure what the accumulator pattern should be in this case either, but the sane (read: non-assignment) way to implement this in python would be simply using `replace` :)

Comment: @poke Thank you, I changed my `butends`. But `ends('a')` yields `a` whcih complies with the spec, or doesn't it?

Comment: @poke If the length is less than 2, return the original string unchanged.

Comment: @Hyperboreus Oh, yes, you’re right. I was seeing things…